# Cómo obtener el URL del archivo del input file?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de obtener la URL de un archivo cargado con un input file pero lo quiero optener con puro javascript

Comment: *obtener la URL de un archivo cargado con un input file*... ¿o sea...?

Comment: El archivo contiene una URL y quieres leer el archivo para sacar la URL?

Comment: Lo que quiero es optener la la dirección del archivo

Comment: Puedes obtener el nombre del archivo. No la ruta local en el equipo desde donde se elige ese archivo. Sería un agujero de privacidad grave.

Answer (score 1):

Por seguridad el navegador no tiene acceso a ese dato, lo que si puede hacer es obtener el nombre del archivo:

```js
function getUrl(){
  var url = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0].name;
  alert(url);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile" onchange="getUrl();">
```